# Is there a dynamesh feature (to sculpt) avaivable like in zbrush?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

In zbrush there is a feature called dynamesh, it recalculates the mesh based on your model. So that you can sculpt with it, just like clay.

Is there a similar tool/function in blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a **different** functionality (*Dyntopo*) but not quite like *Dynamesh* though.

*Dynamesh* will provide a nice quad topology, while *Dyntopo* will leave a nasty triangulated topology with many vertices having more than 4 edges - it will create triangle fans.

Triangle fans are big problem for Blender sculpting, because the smooth brush cannot smooth them perfectly (also in Zbrush there is an alternate smoothing method that can do that).

*Dynamesh* can also perform volumetric (and non-manifold) booleans on sculpted mesh. There isn't such functionality in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is similar function.
Go to sculptmode and enable Dyntopo:

[image]